# Link to and display an image on an Access 2013 App view

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint

I am using Access 2013 with our enterprise Office 365 Sharepoint site to create a simple Access App. I'm unsure of all the terminology--the main point is that this is an Access App as opposed to a desktop application. I am wondering if there is a way to display an image on a list view, where the image source is a data field. Here's what I can do so far and where I get stuck:

- I can add a picture control. I can set the picture to a permanent URL that displays just fine in the view. However, this is a permanent setting for the view of any record.
- I can add a URL field to the table. It's easy to pick the URL in datasheet view, and on list view, it's difficult to change the URL, but clicking on it will pop up the image (or whatever link) in a new tab or window.
- I can create a Web Browser Control. I can have this control source be the URL frame. When I look at this view using an IE browser, I get something that looks like an iFrame. However, no matter what URL I try, the content will not load.

  - More clarification here: Depending on whether I try Flickr or an image hosted on my own OneDrive, I get different errors. One of the errors I get (tyring to use my own OneDrive with publicly shared image) is: "To help protect the security of information you enter into this website, the publisher of this content does not allow it to be displayed in a frame."
  - More information: If I link to a publicly shared image from Google Drive, then the Web Browser Control does in fact show the image. This is not ideal, and I'd rather be able to dynamically change the link for the Picture Control, as opposed to embedding web content.

This is where I am stuck on two avenues. (A) The Web Browser Control will not show any content (maybe this is a security setting of my institution's Sharepoint 2013?). And (B) I cannot figure out how to dynamically change the URL for the picture control. Option B may be possible with a macro, but macros in Access Apps are different than desktop version and much more limited in capability. And I'm not good at either set of macros. Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: Sorry! Looks like it is still here. Should I just delete it and repost it? @MaxVernon ... if I don't hear from you within a day or so, I'll go ahead and do that. Thanks!